# LNK2005 with libpq as static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, libpq

I'm writing an application that links all 3rd party code via static libraries (including tinyxml2, sqlite3, openssl and libpq); everything is working fine beyond whenever I try to link to libpqd.lib - having used the 9.1.9 and 9.2.4 sources - I'm getting:

```
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __dosmaperr already defined in libpqd.lib(win32error.obj)
```

This is the only error, and my searching so far has been fruitless. Note that I'm using the Multi-threaded Debug runtime library `/MTd` in all the libraries, which postgresql doesn't have by default; I've manually patched the win32.mak to use `/MTd` and `/MT` in place of the previously unconfigurable `/MDd` and `/MD`. This resolved some previous linker errors, but don't think it's related to this final one, as it was present prior.

I compile libpq via:

```
nmake /f win32.mak DEBUG=1
```

and link to it by:

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "libpqd.lib" )
```

The library directory is configured within the project, and the library is copied into this folder, so I know it's the correct one being used.

This is usually an error easily resolved, but I'm not sure where to look anymore!

A thread does exist about this on the postgresql site, but doesn't appear to have been resolved: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/39E6FC4547C24F9884435E23698B11DC@HIRO57887DE653

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having issues with it even with converting the project to /MDd, I decided to drop into the source.

`<your_path>\postgresql-9.2.4\src\port\win32error.c` -> comment out, or `#if 0` the function `_dosmaperr`.

The libraries are generated and the application runs fine.

Doing a `grep -R _dosmaperr ./` only revealed this one method; but `include/port/win32.h` and `include/pg_config_os.h` both had it as an extern.

Is a bit late for my mind to make proper head/tail of it, so good enough for now!

Comment: Thank you man! Did it really work well? I mean with patched sources

Comment: I have removed win32error.c from the libpq compilation, and everything looks like working after that.